# Jquery get & display live radio values

Tags: jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I have a form containing radio buttons. These are named option1, option2, and option3. Each one of these radio buttons has 3 different potential values.

I need to display the currently "checked" value below the form. I have been following the jquery guide and getting massively confused.

```
<script>
function displayVals() {
  var opt1 = $('input:radio[name=option1]:checked').val() || [];
  var opt2 = $('input:radio[name=option2]:checked').val() || [];
  var opt3 = $('input:radio[name=option3]:checked').val() || [];
  $("p").html("First item is " + opt1.join(", ") + " the second is " + opt2.join(", ") + " and third is " + opt3.join(", ") + ".");
}

$("input").change(displayVals);
displayVals();
```

However, nothing displays below the form. For example, option1 could be either White, Red or Black. If they check black, I need it to say "First item is black the second is whatever and the third is whatever." Below the form updating each time one of the values changes.

Comment: I bet this things throws an exception, because strings don't have a `join` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Here is the fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sahil_kapoor/3LUBG/)

```
function displayVals() {
  var opt1 = $('input:radio[name=option1]:checked').val() || '';
  var opt2 = $('input:radio[name=option2]:checked').val() || '';
  var opt3 = $('input:radio[name=option3]:checked').val() || '';
  $("p").html("First item is " + opt1 + ", the second is " + opt2 + ", and third is " + opt3 + ",.");
}

$("input:radio").click(displayVals);
displayVals();​
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HdtEj/ I added this to the actual code im using but it doesnt work, does it require ID's?

Comment: Your fiddle did not have a "<p>" tag I added it here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sahil_kapoor/HdtEj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`val()` returns a string or `undefined` and never an array. So this should be

```
function displayVals() {
    var opt1 = $('input:radio[name=option1]:checked').val() || 'not selected';
    var opt2 = $('input:radio[name=option2]:checked').val() || 'not selected';
    var opt3 = $('input:radio[name=option3]:checked').val() || 'not selected';

    $("p").html("First item is " + opt1 + " the second is " + opt2 + " and third is " + opt3 + ".");
}
```